# Reading files which contain unquoted newline characters in text fields using R

Tags: regex, r, newline, read.table

I am trying to read a large table into R but one of the text fields occasionally contains one or more unquoted, un-escaped newline characters (`\n`), thus the `read.table()` function is not able to easily import this file. The file is pipe delimited and the text fields are not quoted.

I can read it in if I pass the argument `fill=T` with `read.table()` but, of course, rows with newline characters in a text field are be corrupted by this.

I have successfully been able to use `f <- readChar(fname, nchars=file.info(fname)["size"], TRUE)` to read sub-segments of the file, then use `gsub()` to search and destroy the offending newline characters. (see code below) However, the full file is > 100mb, so `gsub()` does little more than turn my laptop into a hand-warmer (it's still trying to gsub all the newline characters as I write this).

Anyone have any suggestions for how to efficiently read in a file like this?

It seems like there should be some way of telling R to expect a certain number of delimiters before expecting a newline, but I haven't been able to find any way to do this in the documentation.

Sorry, this seems like it should be easy, but it's really been stumping me, and I have not been able to find anything in stackoverflow or google offering a solution.

Here is the code I've tried so far:

attempt 1:

```
fdat = read.table(file=fname, 
            allowEscapes=F,
            stringsAsFactors=F,
            quote="", 
            fill=T,
            strip.white=T,
            comment.char="",
            header=T, 
            sep="|")
```

attempt 2:

```
f <- readChar(fname, nchars=file.info(fname)["size"], TRUE)
f2 = gsub(pattern="\n(?!NCT)",replacement=" ",x=f, perl=T)
fdat = read.table(text=f2,
            allowEscapes=F,
            stringsAsFactors=F,
            quote="", 
            fill=F,
            strip.white=T,
            comment.char="",
            header=T, 
            sep="|")
```

Here are a few lines from the file:

```
NCT_ID|DOWNLOAD_DATE|DOWNLOAD_DATE_DT|ORG_STUDY_ID|BRIEF_TITLE|OFFICIAL_TITLE|ACRONYM|SOURCE|HAS_DMC|OVERALL_STATUS|START_DATE|COMPLETION_DATE|COMPLETION_DATE_TYPE|PRIMARY_COMPLETION_DATE|PRIMARY_COMPLETION_DATE_TYPE|PHASE|STUDY_TYPE|STUDY_DESIGN|NUMBER_OF_ARMS|NUMBER_OF_GROUPS|ENROLLMENT_TYPE|ENROLLMENT|BIOSPEC_RETENTION|BIOSPEC_DESCR|GENDER|MINIMUM_AGE|MAXIMUM_AGE|HEALTHY_VOLUNTEERS|SAMPLING_METHOD|STUDY_POP|VERIFICATION_DATE|LASTCHANGED_DATE|FIRSTRECEIVED_DATE|IS_SECTION_801|IS_FDA_REGULATED|WHY_STOPPED|HAS_EXPANDED_ACCESS|FIRSTRECEIVED_RESULTS_DATE|URL|TARGET_DURATION|STUDY_RANK
NCT00000105|Information obtained from ClinicalTrials.gov on September 25, 2012|9/25/2012|2002LS032|Vaccination With Tetanus and KLH to Assess Immune Responses.|Vaccination With Tetanus Toxoid and Keyhole Limpet Hemocyanin (KLH) to Assess Antigen-Specific Immune Responses||Masonic Cancer Center, University of Minnesota|Yes|Terminated|July 2002|March 2012|Actual|March 2012|Actual|N/A|Observational|Observational Model:  Case Control, Time Perspective:  Prospective||3|Actual|112|Samples With DNA|analysis of blood samples before and 4 weeks postvaccination|Both|18 Years|N/A|Accepts Healthy Volunteers|Probability Sample|-  Normal volunteers

          -  Patients with Cancer (breast, melanoma, hematologic)

          -  Transplant patients (umbilical cord blood transplant, autologous transplant)

          -  Patients receiving other cancer vaccines|March 2012|March 26, 2012|November 3, 1999|Yes|Yes|Replaced by another study.|No||http://clinicaltrials.gov/show/NCT00000105||6670
NCT00000106|Information obtained from ClinicalTrials.gov on September 25, 2012|9/25/2012|NCRR-M01RR03186-9943|41.8 Degree Centigrade Whole Body Hyperthermia for the Treatment of Rheumatoid Diseases|||National Center for Research Resources (NCRR)||Active, not recruiting||||||N/A|Interventional|Allocation:  Randomized, Intervention Model:  Parallel Assignment, Primary Purpose:  Treatment|||||||Both|18 Years|65 Years|No|||November 2000|June 23, 2005|January 18, 2000||||No||http://clinicaltrials.gov/show/NCT00000106||7998
```

As can be seen, this sample lines from my problem file include the header (line #1), a problematic line (line #2), and a non-problematic line (line #3). Each non-header line starts with NCT and ends with \n (this was leveraged in gsub's regular expression).

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no way to solve it using `read.table`. Sadly, it doesn't allow to change the "record separator" as awk can do, for example.

Your attempt 2 failed because the DOS format newline is \r\n (0x0d 0x0a) and only \n is matched by `gsub`. Say you have following file:

```
NCTa|b|c
NCT1|how
are
you?|well
NCT2|are
you
sure?|yes
```

Then look at the output of your second command:

```
f2 <- gsub(pattern="\n(?!NCT)",replacement=" ",x=f, perl=TRUE)
f2
# [1] "NCTa|b|c\r\nNCT1|how\r are\r you?|well\r\nNCT2|are\r you\r sure?|yes\r "
```

So you have to remove `\r` too. Just fix it to:

```
f2 <- gsub(pattern="\r?\n(?!NCT)",replacement=" ",x=f, perl=TRUE)
```

And it will work.

Regarding performance, you can try to `readChar` it by smaller chunks in a loop, `gsub` them and write them back to file, then `read.table` it. Just an idea.

Comment: That is interesting to know that regex pattern will not work correctly with dos; it worked fine on my mac, aside from the execution time.